# Looking to yield integer number from subtracting DateTime.LocalNow() - VarDate

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I was hoping if someone could help me. I am a bit of a Novice with Power Query and I am working on the Office Add in using Office 2010.

I am trying to subtract two dates to receive an integer number however with little success.

Below I get a number to decimal places

```
= if [C Date] = null then DateTime.LocalNow() - DateTime.LocalNow() else [C Date] - DateTime.LocalNow()
```

I have tried the below variation of the formula in order to yield an integer however, this returns an error.

```
if [C Date] = null then 
Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) - Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
else 
[C Date] - Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
```

Can anyone please offer advice to how I can yield for example 1 rather than 1.2098217 (for example)

Comment: There are also several [number functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/number-functions) that you can use to round to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Duration.Days](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/m/duration-days) function:

```
if [C Date] = null then 0 else Duration.Days([C Date] - DateTime.LocalNow())
```

[image: results]

If you want positive values, you can switch `[C Date] - DateTime.LocalNow()` to `DateTime.LocalNow() - [C Date]`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Works perfect